# Preferred way to Copy & paste multiple files/folders without bothering SVN

Tags: svn

I have directory that keeps a number of 3rd party libraries. It is under SVN control and I need to make a major change in it which involves creating new sub-directories and replacing some files/sub-folders. If I do this manually (i.e. simple copy & paste), SVN gets bothered saying 'blublu' directory is not a working copy. If I want to add the directory to the version control with svn add command then it says the working copy is locked.

My question here is what is the best way to copy such massive amount of subfolders and files into a directory that is under SVN control without having these commit/add problems (e.g. not a working copy and lock). The following are some examples to these error messages that are issued when I attempt to commit/add  the manually copied files/folders to so mentioned directory:

svn: Working copy '.' locked

svn: 'exception' is not a working copy directory

svn: Can't open file 'exception/.svn/entries': Permission denied

Comment: Time to use the Git, it has `git add -A` for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try

> svn add --force *

?

Comment: This returned the following:

> svn add --force *

svn: Working copy '.' locked

svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)

Comment: did you delete some folder without notifing svn and replace the folder with the same name ? this is wrong operation as it will lock the svn working copy.

Comment: I did not delete the folder but I removed its contents so that I can copy the new contents.

Comment: did you remove/replace the .svn directory ?

Comment: well, I removed the contents in Nautilus file browser which normally does not show hidden files including .svn So, I think everything has gone. Isn't there a way for SVN to create fresh .svn directories ?

Comment: I better create a fesh snapshot of the branch and start all over but when I do this, I don't want to get into the same trap but at the sametime I need to have the freedom of this manual copying business considering that the changes are a lot (lots of generated stuff). Could you please tell me step by step what I should do in my fresh snapshot so that I don't get into the same problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please consider some gui svn client such as NautilusSvn and RapidSVN.

Comment: the bottom line is all .svn directory and its file is unmodified.. even the .svn directory in your sub-sub-sub-sub-xxx-directionary in your working copy.

Comment: Also, newly added directory should not having .svn directory in it. you may copy this folder from your teammate so this may happen.